# Does 3x22μF mean three capacitors of 22μF in parallel or series?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, schematics, 5v

In the following schematic (TPS63061) several capacitors are denoted as multiples. As a newbie I am unfamiliar with this notation: does 3x22μF mean three capacitors of 22μF in parallel or series?

[image: Circuit for TPS63060]
See figure 8 here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63061.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are in parallel as mentioned in the datasheet in order to obtain a largish capacitance with SMD parts:

> For the output capacitor, use of a small ceramic capacitor placed as close as possible to the VOUT and PGND
>   pins of the device is recommended. If, for any reason, the application requires the use of large capacitors which
>   can not be placed close to the device, use a smaller ceramic capacitor in parallel to the large capacitor. The
>   small capacitor should be placed as close as possible to the VOUT and PGND pins of the device. **The
>   recommended typical output capacitor value is 66 µF** with a variance as outlined in Table 1.

(Emphasis mine.)

As for the input

> To improve transient behavior of the regulator and EMI behavior of the total power supply circuit, this design suggests a **minimum input capacitance of 20 μF**.

Honestly, I'm not sure why you'd want two 10μF caps there instead of just one 22μF if you're going to BOM those for the output anyway. If you're doing this for production, you'd have take out your calculator and add parts costs to insertion costs and consider the trade-off in board space etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough answer and taking the time to also read the data sheet. this helped me a lot.